# Tire Pressure Monitors during very cold temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

As outside temperature decreases by 10 degrees Fahrenheit, tire pressure decreases 1 psi. However, in very cold temperatures of -10 degrees Fahrenheit, the vehicle TPMS indicates low pressure but the tire pressure is at the normal pressure. Has water vapor inside the tire condensed and frozen on the TPMS tire sensor making it unreliable?

Comment: Not too sure but I do think that you're right about freezing of water vapour. It does form a coating of ice making the TPSM tire sensor unreliable. There might be more reasons to its reading but its probably just a malfunction due to the ice coating.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you checked your spare tire? If your car only has a TPMS light and not individual readouts, *and* your spare has a TPMS sensor in it, that may well be what's triggering the light. Source: it's happened to me before.

Answer (score 3):

Some tire pressure monitors use sensors to measure air pressure directly. Other systems measure changes in wheel speed as an indirect measure of pressure, if a wheel increases the number of revolutions per distance traveled it means the diameter of the wheel has decreased which is a sign that the pressure in the tire has dropped.

- If your car has actual pressure sensors then ice is a possibility, or the cold temperatures have cause some other glitch
- If your car uses wheel speed then it's a sign that the pressure in one of the tires has dropped enough to trip the threshold. This may not be that much, I've seen a drop of 6 psi cause a pressure drop warning. It could also be an issue with a wheel speed sensor, however that's pretty unlikely

Comment: Unless the tire is slipping relative to the wheel, your proposal does not work.

Comment: I don't follow you @JonCuster

Comment: The inflation level of the tire does not impact the number of revolutions per distance traveled unless the tire slips (rotates) relative to the wheel. The same length of tread rolls on the road per wheel rotation. Further, the 'distance traveled' is computed from the number of revolutions anyway, not measured independently.

Comment: Not true @JonCuster, an inflated tire spins less than a deflated one over distance. This is how many TPMS systems work.

Comment: So the steel belts and the nice beefy tread change length with small changes in inflation? Again, unless the tire is slipping relative to the wheel, one wheel rotation is one length of tread on the road. And we won't go into tread wear over time being flagged as a pressure issue.

Comment: The steel doesn't change length, but the diameter of the wheel changes @JonCuster.

Comment: Again - the outer tread of the tire does not change length. One rotation of the wheel means one rotation of the tire and tread. If the tread does not change length one rotation results in the length of the tread traversing the ground. The tire is not a balloon.

Comment: Even if the turns-to-distance ratio does change, how does the system know the distance traveled independently of the number of revolutions?

Comment: @TannerSwett that's an interesting problem.  GPS would be one way (it's accurate enough with sufficient averaging), or you could treat the wheel(s) doing the fewest revolutions  as good, and look for one (or more) increasing.  That would fail to trigger on a uniform drop across all the wheels.

Comment: @TannerSwett: It compares readings from multiple wheels; if one wheel is significantly different to the others it's likely that one needs attention.

Comment: @GdD if the diameter of a circle changes, the circumference necessarily changes (their ratio is fixed to π), and the circumference is the tread length. So your previous comment doesn't make sense as written. However the softer a tyre is, the more it will deform, and the less the unqualified term "diameter" applies. You end up reducing the distance from the contact patch to the axis of rotation, which is a sort of effective radius of the motion rather than the tyre.  Doubling that gives you something that looks a little like a diameter but is no more of one than the width of the letter "D".

Comment: @JonCuster Indirect TPMS is a thing that definitely exists and works. https://www.theautopian.com/how-indirect-tire-pressure-monitoring-systems-work-and-why-we-should-celebrate-their-return/ https://www.bridgestonetire.com/learn/maintenance/tire-pressure-monitoring-system-how-tpms-works/

Comment: @TannerSwett - The indirect system uses the anti-lock braking system to count the tire rotations.